# Flash Event Phases?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

Could someone simply explain the 3 phases in the Flash Event framework, please?

By event phases, I mean:

- `CAPTURING_PHASE`
- `AT_TARGET`
- `BUBBLING_PHASE`

To be clear, I'm talking about `flash.events.Event` and subclasses.

An in-depth example would be *fantastic*. What happens when you click on a nested `MovieClip`?

Comment: Good question. I'm tracking down a problem with a Stack Overflow (a real one, ActonScript error #1023) that I'm pretty sure has something to do with MouseEvent propagation in AIR. I'm having a hard time getting my head around the event model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> With event propagation you're dealing with three "phases" of an event (see Figure 2). Each phase represents a path or the location of an event as it works itself through the display objects in Flash that relate to that event. The three phases of an event are capturing, at target, and bubbling:

- **Capturing phase**: This represents the
  parent objects of the target object
  from which the event originated. Any
  propagated event starts with the
  topmost parent (stage) and works
  down the display object hierarchy
  until reaching the original target.
- **At target phase**: The target phase is
  the phase where the event is at the
  target object or the object from
  which the event originated. Unlike
  the capturing and bubbling phases,
  this phase always relates to only
  one object, the target object.
- **Bubbling phase**: When an event
  "bubbles" it follows the reverse
  path of the capturing phase and
  works its way back up the parent
  hierarchy of the target object until
  reaching the top-most parent or
  stage.

Blatantly stolen from: [Introduction to event handling in ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you think you could explain what they're used for, perhaps with an example or two? What happens when I click on a nested MovieClip?

Comment: Link should be: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wrote a few articles on events propagation, custom events in Flash etc.

You can find the article here along with source code and working examples:

http://www.popamihai.com/2010/10/flex/event-propagation-capturing-phase-targeting-phase-and-bubbling-phase/

> The **capturing phase** is occurs **from the outside to the inside**, from the
>   outermost parent container (in this case the Application tag) to the
>   immediate parent (VGroup tag) of the target object.
>
> After all the ancestors are checked for listeners Flex starts the
>   **targeting phase.**
>
> The **targeting phase** is the second phase in the event propagation
>   mechanism and in this phase Flex checks for event listeners on the
>   target object itself.
>
> The third and last phase of the event propagation mechanism is the
>   **bubbling phase.** Alter the targeting phase, Flex now checks all the
>   parent containers of the target object for event listeners. This check
>   occurs from the inside to the outside, from the immediate parent of
>   the target object to the outermost parent container – in this case the
>   Application tag.