# I need help bubbling an event in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

I want to have the parent of my class handle the event first, then I want to have the child handle the event.  Is there a way to explicitly bubble the event up?  I want to do something like this:

```
...
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, characterClicked);
...

private function characterClicked(e:Event):void{
// pass event to parent to be handled first
...
}
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: object1 adds object2.  object2 gets clicked.  Object2 will get the event first.  I want object2 to bubble the event to object1, and then handle the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. Is seems hackish, but it works.  If there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

```
...
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, characterClicked);
...

private function characterClicked(e:Event):void{
// pass event to parent to be handled first
this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, characterClicked); //prevent infinite loop
            dispatchEvent(e); // send event to parent object
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, characterClicked);
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
...
}
```

Comment: You dont have to explicitly redispatch the event to catch the event in the parent.

In your situation I would add an event listener in the parent, process the event in the parent and once the parent has finished event processing I would call a function on the child. This is assuming there is just 1 child for each parent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I need to handle this in the child class, not in the parent.  The parent container code should not change.

Answer (score 5):

There are three "phases" of an event; [Capture, At target and Bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348476/flash-event-phases). They occur in this order, meaning that if you set an event listener to be in the capture phase it will always fire before one set regularly (which would mean either at target or bubble).

Like so:

```
// in parent, third argument is "use capture"
child.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClickInParent, true); 

// in child, add listener as usual
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
```

Now, your parent event listener will always fire first!

Comment: Thanks, +1 for a solution that works.  I am still looking for a way to do this from within the child object.  I won't always be writing the code that uses this class (therefor I can't rely on other programmers to set the third parameter to true as in your example).  Do you know of a way to do this from within the child?

Comment: If you explain why you need to do this I can probably come up with something.

Comment: In short there is a global boolean flag being used in the program.  Some objects being clicked will result in the flag being toggled on, some things being clicked toggle the flag off (along with other actions).  When my character gets clicked I need the flag toggled on (no matter who it's parent is).   So, I need to make sure that my parent does what it needs to do, then I can toggle this flag on and do the other things the character needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to handle the listener in the parent instead of the child it might be easier. Then you could just pass the event to the child when you're done:

```
// inside parent class:
childObj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCharacterClicked);

private function onCharacterClicked(e:Event):void {
    // do parent stuff first
    // ...

    // then pass event to child 
    childObj.onCharacterClicked(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work.  I am writing a class and I have no control over what the parent container will be. This must be done in the child object.